# Printing a binary representation of float/double gives the same result for two different numbers

Tags: c, ansi-c

I have to print a binary representation (from the memory) for float / doubles. While it's working pretty nicely for integers, I got strange behavior for some floats.

I mean, the results for 3.14 and 21.37 are the same (as double). For 8.5 I'm getting 0s.

21.37 as double:

0101000111101011100001010001111101010001111010111000010100011111

3.14 as double:

0101000111101011100001010001111101010001111010111000010100011111

8.5 as double:

0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

```
#include <stdio.h>
int printBit(int c, int i) {
    return (c & (1 << (i - 1))) ? 1 : 0;
}

int main()
{
    double f;
    int *b;
    scanf("%lf", &f);

    b = &f;

    int i;
    printf("Jako double: \n");
    for (i = sizeof(f) * 8; i > 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%i", printBit(*b, i));
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Well, we could say that this code is violating *strict aliasing* rule and stop there...Also you are assuming `double` to be the same size as `int` for some reason.

Comment: `sizeof(double)` is usually  larger than `sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You function for sure is not printing the correct data.

The problem is that the sizeof(int) in your system is smaller than sizeof(double). There is strict aliasing problem as well. This is actually strictly theoretical here, but generally speaking do not use pointer punning at all.

So how to pun types:

1. Use unions
2. Use memcpy
3. Use char array.

method 1 & 3 are demonstrated below.

Union punning (https://godbolt.org/z/qxi8sK)

```
void prinFloatAsUnsigned(float x)
{
    union
    {
        uint32_t u;
        float f;
    }u32 = {.f = x};

    printf("sizeof(float) = %zu flaot as unsigned = 0x%x\n", sizeof(float), u32.u);
}

int main(void)
{
    prinFloatAsUnsigned(3.14f);
}
```

memcpy method

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void printasbin(void *buf)
{
    uint64_t val;

    memcpy(&val, buf, sizeof(val));
    for(int x = 63; x >=0; x--)
        printf("%c", '0' + !!(val & (1ULL << x)));
    printf("\n");
}


int main(void)
{
    double x = 3.14;
    printf("%f = \t",x);
    printasbin(&x);
    x = 21.37;
    printf("%f = \t",x);
    printasbin(&x);
    x = 8.5;
    printf("%f = \t",x);
    printasbin(&x);
}
```

result:

```
3.140000  =     0100000000001001000111101011100001010001111010111000010100011111
21.370000 =     0100000000110101010111101011100001010001111010111000010100011111
8.500000  =     0100000000100001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3mLHw9

or printed your way (a bit modified - in the IT we count bits form zero)

```
int printBit(void *buff, int i) 
{
    unsigned char *data = buff;
    return !!(data[i / 8] & (1 << (i & 7)));
}


int main(void)
{
    double f = 3.14;
    printf("Jako double: %f\n", f);
    for (int i = sizeof(f) * 8 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d", printBit(&f, i));
    }
    printf("\n");

    f = 21.37;
    printf("Jako double: %f\n", f);
    for (int i = sizeof(f) * 8 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d", printBit(&f, i));
    }
    printf("\n");

    f = 8.5;
    printf("Jako double: %f\n", f);
    for (int i = sizeof(f) * 8 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d", printBit(&f, i));
    }
    printf("\n");
```

result:

```
Jako double: 3.140000
0100000000001001000111101011100001010001111010111000010100011111
Jako double: 21.370000
0100000000110101010111101011100001010001111010111000010100011111
Jako double: 8.500000
0100000000100001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Gn4vpK

Comment: I don't get the `!!` on `!!(val & (1ULL << x))`.

Comment: @KevinKouketsu It is logical `not` `not`

Comment: Yes. But why? `not` `not` logical is not the same as `(val & (1ULL << x))`?

Comment: @KevinKouketsu No it is not. Result of `not` can be only `zero` or `one`

Comment: @KevinKouketsu `!!x` does exactly the same as `x ? 1 : 0`

Comment: You're late to the party but this answer is genuinely helpful. Have an upvote to set it on its way.

Comment: @Bathsheba late but the only who has found the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

The "pragmatic" answer is that `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(double)` are probably not the same on your platform; the latter is probably larger, so you're only reading back part of the `double` which is the same in both cases.

But to delve deeper, the statement `b = &f;` is a violation of *strict aliasing* and so the behaviour of your program is undefined at the point `b` is dereferenced.

A good way round this is to read the memory by casting `&f` to a `const unsigned char*` (that's an exception to the strict aliasing rule), and using pointer arithmetic on that pointer up to `sizeof(f)`.

Comment: I think, strictly speaking, the violation is occurring not at that line, but where the first read access as `int` is happening.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I think you could be correct: I've amended the answer. On that one it's possible that the rules for C and C++ differ, and I'm more of a C++ guy.

Comment: But it not the problem. Integers are usually 32bits, doubles are 64. This is the main problem. Aliasing in this case does not matter

Comment: @P__J__: Indeed, I've been a little more helpful. Thanks for the prompt.